# Ubuntu 14.04 xrdp suddenly not working

Tags: 14.04, xfce, remote-desktop, xrdp

we have ubuntu 14.04 and xrdp+xfce4 running since 2014, few months ago we could not access our ubuntu via remote desktop anymore from windows 10 remote desktop. I reinstalled both xrdp and xfce4 after that it will get a connection partially and fails and then no connection at all.

```
Xsession: X session started for  at Wed Feb 20 14:15:03 EET 2019
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
localuser:pdi_live being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
xfce4-session-Message: ssh-agent is already running

(xfsettingsd:4463): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: RANDR extension is too old, version 1.1. Display settings won't be applied.
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":12.0".

(xfsettingsd:4463): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: XI is not present.

(xfsettingsd:4463): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: Failed to initialize the Xkb extension.

(xfsettingsd:4463): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: Failed to initialize the Accessibility extension.
vmware-user: could not open /proc/fs/vmblock/dev

** (process:4474): CRITICAL **: bluez.vala:104: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.81" (uid=1005 pid=4474 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indi") interface="org.bluez.Manager" member="DefaultAdapter" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=479 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")

(zeitgeist-datahub:4496): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
Failure: Module initialization failed


** (process:4530): CRITICAL **: volume_control_set_volume_internal: assertion '_tmp1_ == PA_CONTEXT_READY' failed
** (process:4530): CRITICAL **: file /build/buildd/indicator-sound-12.10.2+14.04.20140401/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/volume-control.c: line 1775: uncaught error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface (g-dbus-error-quark, 16)
Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gtk.vfs.Daemon: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)

(xfsettingsd:4463): GVFS-CRITICAL **: fill_mountable_info: assertion 'proxy != NULL' failed
```

Any hints would be helpful about how to fix this.